# How to find out depricated API for xamarin.ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

We know Apple is deprecating some API’s on their new version releases. They are adding the information on the below pages.

We could find the depricated API using the below link for the native ios applications . 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017084-SW44

Similarly, How can I find the depricated API for xamarin ios applications?

Also Where can I find the different mono touch version and deprecated API in it?

Thanks in Advance

Roshil

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/ios/api_changes/

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction-to-ios10/#Deprecated_APIs